# Blank page on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I just try to create a profile page i create a **Route** like this:

```
Route::get('profile/{id}/{name}','ProfileController@index');
```

**and the index function like this :**

```
public function index($id,$name)
{
    $user = \App\User::find($id);
    return view('pages.profile',compact('user'));
}
```

**profile view:**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;padding: 30px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="proPic"><img src="{{user->image}}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

but when I lunch the link i get a blank page

Comment: Have you tried just writing something in the view to make sure the view is even presented? Have you tried testing you even get to the controller function?

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank yes i try to remove user data from the view and return just view('page.profile') and it work fine but when i passe user data it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a default installation, you probably need to have:

`@extends('layouts.app')`

instead of

`@extends('app')`

and change

`{{user->image}}`

to

`{{ $user->image }}`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks clean, a blank page can occur when laravel doesn't displays errors. I'd recommand you to :
1- Check the server response (HTTP code, content...)
2- Check your logs, maybe you'll discover a problem of configuration

Comment: home page and the others works fine so i dont think that problem caused by server, maybe '2' where can i find logs ?

Comment: /storage/logs/laravel-XXXX-XX-XX.log
(last error at the end of the file)